# OWL Ontology (giving property restrictions)

Tags: ontology, owl, protege

I am currently working on the OWL Ontology I have a question in regard to property.

To be frankly saying, I don't really see the importance of giving a property restriction to class.

For example,

Product (class) has manufacturer (property) some Manufacturer.

In this case this means that one product has at least one manufacturer.

However, then why not just do object property assertions by

a plastic model (an individual of the product) has manufacturer (object property) DOCOMO (an instance of the manufacturer) ?

Do I have to do both? enve if I don't do the first thing, the reasoner says there is no problem. Why Do i have to do both?

Comment: Rephrase "reasoner says there is no problem" to make it clear what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property restriction asserts something about a set of individuals, not just a single individual. Consider the property restriction:

```
Every man likes a woman. (i.e. "man subClassOf like some woman")
```

vs the property assertion:

```
John likes Mary. (i.e. "{John} subClassOf like some {Mary}")
```

where `{John}` and `{Mary}` are classes with a single individual, but `man` and `woman` are classes with 0 or more individuals.

Comment: so do we have to do both in the case of your example? I was saying that if we can give individuals relationship why bother giving relationship between classes?

Comment: My example demonstrates that property assertion and property restriction are two different things. You should use one or the other or both depending on what you want to say. What do you want to say?