# Ontologies: Why should I define object restrictions on a class if I can assign a property directly to the individual?

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology

This question is actually the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639125/owl-ontology-giving-property-restrictions). The above answer answers the question *"What is the difference between Property Restriction and Property Assertion?"* But in my opinion it does not answer the question (of the OP) :

> Why should I use Property Restrictions at all?

Let's say

```
Every man likes a woman. (i.e. "man subClassOf like some woman")
```

For what use is this other than assigning `likes` property, e.g. `like some {Mary}`, to every single (man) individual (what I have to do anyway, if I do the Property Restriction).

Currently I am building a basic ontology, but after creating the classes I'm not sure what advantage I get, when I put those Property Restrictions on it. Because, fetching an individual via e.g.

```
SELECT ?subject ?likes
WHERE { 
   ?subject rdfs:subClassOf :man;
             :like ?likes .
}
```

will get me the data whether I have this `PropertyRestriction` or not (maybe this assumption is not correct).

Maybe a small example will help me to understand what I can use it for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those places where OWL is a bit counter-intuitive.  Property restrictions are used for classification.  For example, given the assertion `"man subClassOf like some woman"`, you can find that some object with the `like` property with an object that is a member of `woman` is a `man`.

I suspect what you're looking for is somewhat the opposite: Do all members of `man` have a `likes` property that is a member of `woman`?  That is something OWL isn't very good at answering, mostly because of the [Open-World Assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-world_assumption). However, if you want to do this in RDF, using SPARQL to query the data, then it's relatively easy:

```
SELECT ?subject
WHERE {
   ?subject a :Man .
   FILTER NOT EXISTS {
      ?subject :likes ?woman .
      ?woman a :Woman .
   }
}
```

Which basically states that if a member of `man` has neither a `likes` property or the `likes` property is not a member of `woman`, then the individual fails to meet the `every many likes a woman` criteria.  Note that no subclassing is necessary here.  Members of `man` use the `likes` property to specify an individual.  Again following the references example an RDF specification would be:

```
:John :likes :Mary .
:Mary a :Woman .
:John a :Man .
```

Where Turtle syntax allows `a` in place of `rdf:type`.

Note also that you can still infer membership of `man`:

```
CONSTRUCT {
   ?subject a :Man .
}
WHERE {
   ?subject :likes ?object .
   ?object a :Woman .
   FILTER NOT EXISTS {
      ?subject a :Man .
   }
}
```

...which states that if an individual is not already a member of `man` and has a `likes` property that is a member of `man`, we infer that the individual is a member of `man` by returning a set of triples (as opposed to SELECTing the variable bindings in a match).

So back to the original question of "Why use property restrictions?".  Use these if you want to do classification per the first paragraph in this response.  OWL excels at that kind of classification.  Otherwise, it will be worth looking at a SPARQL-based solution.

For reference, a couple of SPARQL-based W3C proposals have been around for a while - take a look at [SPIN](https://www.w3.org/Submission/spin-overview/) and [SHACL](https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl/), the latter of which is now a working draft.

Comment: Also thanks for pointing out SPIN and SHACL, especially SHACL looks awesome.

Answer (score 0):

It's useful to know the existential restrictions exists when there are no individuals. Depending on your needs, this might be unnecessary.